# Why does Docker keep around the stopped containers?

Tags: docker

What's the reason that stopped containers are kept around? Can they be restarted in any way?

Comment: Because you want to keep an uncommitted changes around in the event that the container stopped unexpectedly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you want to keep uncommitted changes around for recovery, image creation, or general inspection.

Stopped containers can be restarted with the command `docker start <container-name>` and can be viewed with a `docker ps -a`

In addition you can commit changes for any container (even if the container is stopped) to your local registry with a `docker commit <container-name> <repository>:<tag>`